# Error - Unable to Submit for Review though information was provided in the App privacy section

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit updated app version/build in App Store Connect. Though the user with Admin role has provided information in the App privacy section, still I'm getting the error saying "Before you can submit this app for review, an Admin must provide information about the app’s privacy practices in the App Privacy section".

[image]

Why am I facing this problem? There is no error message in the App Privacy section. It displays data types linked to, tracks user etc.,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had to do that yesterday as well, you have to put a link to your privacy policy

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for your response. Privacy policy URL field has been filled already long back.

Answer (score 0):

The information entered in the App privacy section was not published.

After publishing it using the Publish button, the app was successfully submitted for review.